# Showing current time depending on region for Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, time, win-universal-app, region

I thought this is going to be a very simple question yet I can't solve it. In my app I want to display the current time depending on the region setting of the user. If my phone normally displays 17:48, I want my app to show it in this format. If it shows 5:48pm, then the same rule should apply to my app. Yet, whatever I do, it only shows the am/pm version. I am using the System.**DateTime** class. I saw some solutions where I can do like this (setting the time to Austrian time format):

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("t", de-AT);
```

and it works!
However, I don't want to set it manually, but using the region format depending on the users phone setting.
I tried getting the language country name with **CultureInfo.CurrentCulture** like this:

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("t", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Which doesn't work, because CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name always displays en-US, even though my phone is set to Austrian region.
When I use the **GeographicRegion** class and print this:

```
GeographicRegion userRegion = new GeographicRegion();
string region = userRegion.CodeTwoLetter;
```

I will get AT as a string and "Österreich" (= Austria) when printing userRegion.NativeName;

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture should contain the regional settings of the phone user, but for some reason in a UWP app it is set to the (default) language supported by your app. If you add support for de-AT by setting Resource Language="de-AT" in your package.appxmanifest and the users phone language is de-AT you will get de-AT in CurrentCulture. However, the user's language setting can differ from the user's region setting, so this does not help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching I found a way to make it work! I use the DateTimeFormatter class, which does exactly what I want. At least as far as I know.

```
        GeographicRegion userRegion = new GeographicRegion();
        string regionCode = userRegion.CodeTwoLetter;

        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("hour minute", new[] { regionCode });
        string correctTime = timeFormatter.Format(DateTime.Now);           
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("dayofweek month day", new[] { regionCode });
        string correctDate = dateFormatter.Format(DateTime.Now);
```

If someone sees a mistake in that and it won't work in all reagions, please tell me.

Comment: The geographic region (region where the user lives) and the user's regional settings are two separate settings on the phone, so there is no guarantee that you will get the right settings when you use the geographic region.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do this afterwards:
string regionTime = dT.ToString("t");
and it still shows me the time in am. Can you tell me how to print this?

Comment: you may try this. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData(); before  string regionTime = dT.ToString("t");